# What exception should be raised when a function can't be called at this time?

Tags: python, exception

I have an error which turned out to be due to a race between object destruction and a new object being constructed.  The destructor of `foo` must be called before a new `foo` is made, so this fails:

```
A = foo()
...
A = foo() # Error because the first foo object still exists
```

While I'm tracking down all the causes of this, I want to add an exception to the `__init__` method of `foo` in the case where another `foo` still exists.

What is the most pythonic exception to raise?

Comment: " The destructor of foo must be called before a new foo is made" => this looks like a huge design issue to me.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes...but I can't fix it until I understand the code, hence the instrumentation :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new exception of your choice. Best  suited name may be `ObjectAlreadyExistsException`

Comment: You could make it a subclass of e.g. [`RuntimeError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.RuntimeError)